# Beanie raise RevisionIdWasChanged in python

Tags: python, fastapi, mongodb-atlas

I'm using mongodb-atlas(cloud version) and fastAPI for learning to create backend API.

I created this router post that will create users. I tried to raise an exception when trying to create an email that already exist in mongodb-atlas. The code goes like this

```
@user_router.post('/create', summary="Create new user")
async def create_user(data: UserAuth):
   try:
        return await UserService.create_user(data)
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User with this email or username already exist"
        )
```

But the problem is when manually testing this and trying out the API, instead of getting the error message "User with this email or username already exist" I simply just get 500 Internal Server error.

The terminal mention that:

during the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\uvicorn\\protocols\\http\\httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore\[func-returns-value\]
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\uvicorn\\middleware\\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\fastapi\\applications.py", line 1106, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\middleware\\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\middleware\\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, \_send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\middleware\\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\middleware\\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\fastapi\\middleware\\asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\fastapi\\middleware\\asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\starlette\\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\fastapi\\routing.py", line 274, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\fastapi\\routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(\*\*values)
    File "\\Backend\\App\\api\\api_v1\\handlers\\user.py", line 13, in create_user
    return await UserService.create_user(data)
    File "\\Backend\\App\\services\\user_service.py", line 15, in create_user
    await user_in.save()
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\actions.py", line 219, in wrapper
    result = await f(self, \*args, skip_actions=skip_actions, \*\*kwargs)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\utils\\state.py", line 66, in wrapper
    result = await f(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\utils\\self_validation.py", line 12, in wrapper
    return await f(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\documents.py", line 545, in save
    return await self.update(
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\actions.py", line 219, in wrapper
    result = await f(self, \*args, skip_actions=skip_actions, \*\*kwargs)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\utils\\state.py", line 66, in wrapper
    result = await f(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
    File "\\lib\\site-packages\\beanie\\odm\\documents.py", line 670, in update
    raise RevisionIdWasChanged
    beanie.exceptions.RevisionIdWasChanged
```

I have zero idea what this is, I tried to fix it but since I have little understanding about beanie I couldn't comprehend how this is happening.
Please let me know what I can do to resolve this.
I also understand that I only show a snippet of my code if there needs to be added to help understand the issue please let me know, I'll try to give as much more detail as I can.

I haven't tried that much since I got little to no understanding on how and why this occur. My expectation is that this error message shows "User with this email or username already exist"

instead of error 500 Internal Server Error in API docs

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the [`insert`](https://beanie-odm.dev/api-documentation/document/#documentinsert) Beanie method instead of [`save`](https://beanie-odm.dev/api-documentation/document/#documentsave).

`save` can either try to insert or update an object and from [here](https://github.com/roman-right/beanie/blob/72b35f9949989c282930492422a536899271bab3/beanie/odm/documents.py#L714) you can see that it forces the `RevisionIdWasChanged` when it receives a `DuplicateKeyError`. It seems that it is raised even if it's creating a new object.